# My app has crashed android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I get an error when I run my android app on my android device. **It says Unfortunately, GuessingGame has stopped. It was running before but ever since I added a EditText to the layout, it has been crashing. Here is my MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.h2ogaming.numberguessinggame;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



    pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String randText = "";
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Random randGen = new Random();
            int random = randGen.nextInt(5) + 1;
            randText = Integer.toString(random);
            textOne.setText(randText);
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Here is my Activity_Main XML file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="#2288ee">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:text="@string/guess_text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/text_view1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_press" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: post crash  plz ....i mean logcat plz

Comment: Cash? Sorry new to android.

Comment: You need to post the cRash report.  You're probably getting a nullpointerexception I imagine.

Comment: Where can I get that report?

Comment: clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: when you run the project and when the error occures, it shows that error in `LogCat`(Small window in Eclipse itself). If its not showing then goto `Window->ShowView->Other->Android->LogCat` and click ok.. and rebuild your project.. next time it'll show you the error.. and then post that error here.. so that we can understand exactly whats the problem and can help you out in detail..

Comment: @Gunnar enjoy then :)

Comment: @Mitesh thanks will use for future questions. twntee helped me.

Comment: @Gunnar:: Yeah, thats great..:) enjoy.. but, use `LogCat`.. Its very important.. If you were using that, then probably you were able to solve this problem without asking here.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your initialization for components.declare proper all components globally. then initialize it like below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView textOne;
 Button pressMe;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: I used your code but it still didn't work. But for some reason when I clicked clean project, it worked! I don't know how it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: how is that useful ??

Comment: Well I didn't declare my Button and TextView globally. Now I know.